# How to use Regular Expression In visual Studio 2012 coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am having a scenario where i want to click a radio button but its value keeps on changing as you run it again and again, so want to use a regex in place of its value which is a number in the format some what like "[0-9]"

Thanks

Comment: Please vote for the implementation of this feature: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5520782-regularexpression-in-searchproperties

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot search with a regular expression. You can get close.

If part of the string is always present then you can search for items "containing" the fixed part of the string. For example if the text on the button matches `^SomeText[0-9]$` you could search for "contains" `SomeText`. Sometimes that is sufficient.

You could also use a search property that matches several controls, then call the  `FindMatchingControls()` method to return the collection of matching controls. Then write your own code (possibly using a regular expression) to search the collection for the control you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AdrianHHH, you said correctly that we cannot search with regular expression. i did use a code to match the 2nd half of the string a first half of string was comman. Thanks